# Having problems playing .swf file

Tags: flash, swf

I am trying to play an swf file from the link iqtest.dk. That link downloads an swf file. I have tried thousands of methods to play the file but nothing works.

- downloading iswiff or other standalone media player - either says update adobe flash (which I did) or can't play the file (screen will pop up saying "this can only be accessed through iqtest.dk"
- changing mime database file - I don't have a /usr/mime folder so this isn't even relevant
- making a document called flash.html, adding

and playing it in my browser. Again, it pops up with a screen saying "can only be accessed through iqtest.dk"

- opening through firefox - firefox doesn't have a shockwave plugin or adobe flash plugin

I don't know what else to do. I just want to play the file either locally or in my browser.

Comment: You should not have downloaded the file. Gertel's answer below is good, but the best (and should be easiest) method of making this work would be to go back to the page you accessed the file from, and try to simply play it from there instead of downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the flash file is checking what website it is playing on.

SWF files can check the domain they are running from. This can be used to prevent websites from stealing each other's flash games and other such purposes.

In your case it's matching the current domain against the iqtest.dk. The file simply doesn't want to be run from any other domain.

There is a way to try and circumvent this problem, but it's not easy:

- Install a web server (nginx/apache2)
- Put your HTML file and the SWF file in the root of the web server directory
- Edit your hosts file and add `127.0.0.1 iqtest.dk` on a new line (`/etc/hosts` for *nix, `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" for Windows)
- Navigate to http://iqtest.dk/yourhtmlfile.html
- The file should load up and be usable

The downside of this method is that you can no longer reach the real iqtest.dk.

Another way is to decompile/reverse engineer the file and disable the check. You can use programs such as [JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/), [Show My Code](http://www.showmycode.com/) or any other decompiling tool for this purpose.

Please note that depending on your local laws and regulations, decompiling software may be illegal.